# Nginx cache is not cleared when using cloudflare

Tags: nginx, cache, django

My nginx config here:
http://p.ngx.cc/0c

This link http://aa-tour.ru/static/system/css/style.css show me old cached version of file, how to remove it and clear cache?
This is correct (new) version of file http://aa-tour.ru/static/system/css/style.css?v=1

It's just static file. I updated it (added some classes `contact-form`, `contact-form-button`)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236078/how-to-clear-the-cache-of-nginx

sendfile off;

Also disabled cloudflare...

Answer (score 4):

This isn't nginx cache. In your config is absent `proxy_cache`, `fastcgi_cache` and similar directives at all.

File cached by your browser because of the directive `expires 30d;` at 35 line of config. Why did you decide that nginx cache this file?

To previous people who "answered". Guys, read the question attentively, please :D

Comment: I tried open this css file in browsers, which I didn't use before... In FF and Opera...

Comment: In your config is *absent nginx cache directives*. That's all.
Or you show us not full config, may be.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use this bash script to delete your static files from the nginx cache:

- https://github.com/perusio/nginx-cache-purge

Hope it helps.

Comment: I use Ubuntu 13.04, no such file or directory

Comment: ls /var/cache/nginx/