# How do I clear the nginx proxy cache?

Tags: nginx

This is my nginx config:

```
proxy_cache_path  /tmp/nginxcache  levels=1:2  keys_zone=trycatchchris:10m max_size=1g inactive=1440m use_temp_path=off;

server {
    listen 3000;

    server_name trycatchchris.co.uk;
    root /var/www/html/public/;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3001/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        proxy_cache trycatchchris;
        proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control;
        proxy_cache_valid any 1440m;

        proxy_no_cache $cookie_nocache $arg_nocache;
        proxy_cache_bypass $cookie_nocache $arg_nocache;
        add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
    }
}
```

How do I clear the cache?

I've already had a look at [How to clear nginx cache](https://serverfault.com/questions/514365/how-to-clear-nginx-cache) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236078/how-to-clear-the-cache-of-nginx (one points to the other) however there are numerous answers and the question / accepted answer relates to a historical bug - so not really a good reference.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6896903/1663462

In my case:

```
find /tmp/nginxcache -type f -delete
```